# Is "the changes you intend to make will not do us any good" polite?

Tags: word-choice, writing

I would like a polite (formal) way to say:

> The changes you intend to make will not do us any good.

or should I say "intend on making"?

Comment: There's also [The changes you **are intent** on making...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+intent+on+making&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=), which is probably the *least* "polite" way of putting it.

Answer (score 6):

You could say:

"We feel that the intended changes will be of little benefit."

This avoids directly saying "you", which could come across as impolite.

Although not quite the same, you could also use "the proposed changes".

Comment: Thnak you, that's perfect!

Comment: @Nniiss: Strictly speaking, the fact that you're apparently happy with a rephrasing suggests your question is effectively Off Topic "style advice/proofreading". This answer makes no attempt to address the question you *appeared* to ask, about any possible difference between [intend on making,intend to make](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intend+on+making%2Cintend+to+make&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: I wasn't sure how to put it.. I just created my acc

Comment: @FumbleFingers I answered her first question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Also my question was edited by Matt Эллен

Comment: @Nniiss: The general principle is if you want to be polite you tend to remove all personal pronouns, and cast things in the passive. That would be the case regardless of your specific example, so even James' offering is a bit too "direct" (*"The intended changes are felt to be of little benefit"* is the "rule-based" approach). Whatever - I didn't closevote, but I don't much care for *"Please rephrase this more politely"* questions.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, *intend on* is [a common error in English usage](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/intendon.html):

> You can plan on doing something, but you **intend to** do it. Many people confuse these two expressions with each other and mistakenly say “intend on”*. Of course if you are really determined, you can **be intent on doing something**.

Comment: I don't agree that *to intend **on** [doing something]* is an erroneous/ungrammatical form caused by conflation of *intent on/intend to*. As you say, you can *plan on* doing something, so there's nothing apart from convention to stop you *intending on* doing it. And since [I intend on](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+intend+on%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) has been around for centuries, I suggest it's well-established enough to be considered a "standard" grammatical form.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But it's not included in the dictionary (at least not in the famous ones that I checked) and your search yielded 19k results only. I still think it's a common error.

Comment: Yeah, well [I reckon on](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+reckon+on%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) calling it a day then. I'm not about to concede that I'm an incompetent speaker, and you obviously think *intend* has some special quality distinguishing it from words like *plan, reckon* in such constructions, so I don't think either of us is about to change our minds. :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the first answer suggests several *different* improvements, each of which makes it more polite:

(a) It replaces the stark "not do... good" with the softer "little benefit" (which avoids "no" or "not").

(b) "Any" is often added for emphasis, so "not... ANY good" means especially worthless! On the other hand, "will not do us good" sounds awkward.

(c) It adds "We feel that..." which makes it an opinion rather than an absolute (even though it's about benefit to us, so it works out as absolute). Any time you qualify a statement with "in my opinion" you are being a bit more polite.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would be more polite:

> I don't understand how these proposed changes will help you or me.

Comment: yeah, but in a formal letter directly saying "you" could come across as impolite.